# Make img stop pulling things without <br />

Tags: html, css, image

**FOUND OUT THE ANSWER: IT"S DISPLAY:BLOCK;. PLEASE DO NOT DOWN VOTE THIS ANY MORE**

If you put an image in a page (using`<img src="" />`) it always pulls input's and button and some other things to it's right, like it's floating left. What's a simple way to stop this?

Here's samples of what I mean with an img and a button (none work though)

```
<img src="5.gif" /><button style=""></button>
```

I've tried clear:both;, making them float different ways and switching them but nothing seems to work. Is`<br />`the only way?

Comment: have you tried `display: block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the image to display: block

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: It would help you a lot to understand which elements are by default block, and which ones are inline.

Answer (score 1):

use the following style:

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can make your img a block using

```
display: block;
```

or perhaps stopping it from floating by setting its float value to none:

```
float: none;
```

Are you sure that your images are not floated because of a directive in some css file? Firebug can help you.

Comment: I tried float:none; without any other styling and it didn't work. But yeah display:none; works perfect